# Merge problems in R: Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns

Tags: r, merge

I have two tables, both of which are aggregate outputs. I'd like to merge them together - they were both aggregated off the same data, so they have the same column names, but for the sake of edification I thought I'd try the specific by.x and by.y methods in the examples of ?merge.

```
merge(medA,countA, 
      by = c("manager_id", "manager_name", "grouping"))
## this works

merge(medA,countA, 
  by.x = c(medA$manager_id, medA$manager_name, medA$grouping), 
  by.y = c(countA$manager_id, countA$manager_name, countA$grouping))
## this doesn't? 
## Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns
```

It isn't particularly pressing: I can just use the merge that works. But I'm honestly confused why specific by.x and by.y doesn't work. I've googled around for it, but I can't seem to find similar problems. Any thoughts you guys have would be much appreciated.

Comment: specify the `by.x` and `by.y` as character strings as before

Comment: The `merge` help page has an example of using `by.x` and `by.y` which you might find helpful.

Comment: I think you're calling the variable names incorrectly. Try:
`merge(medA,countA, by.x = c("manager_id", "manager_name", "grouping"), by.y = c("manager_id", "manager_name", "grouping"))`

Comment: Huh. Thank you very much everyone - the method you suggested does work. aosmith, I read the ?merge page; it's for merging on one column, I wanted to merge on more than one, which is why I thought of using c(), but it didn't occur to me that I _wouldn't_ have to specify which data it comes from.

Comment: Did you ever find solution to this?

Comment: yes - tsurudak and user20650 were correct, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 14):

Before using     `merge()` also see if the classes of two tables you are trying to merge are same. If you try to merge `data.table` class with `data.frame` in that case also,it will throw this error.